# error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol, c++ project compilation

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, linker

I want to build a project having the following structure:

```
Capture(main project)
    +subproject1
    +subproject2
    +subproject3
     ....
     ....
```

etc
My projects links with opencv libraries.
Although all subprojects build with no errors, when i build my main project(Capture) i got the following errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl cv::detail::CameraParams::CameraParams(struct cv::detail::CameraParams const &)" (??0CameraParams@detail@cv@@$$FQEAA@AEBU012@@Z)    Capture D:\Performance_capt\source\Capture\CapturingForm.obj    1
```

Any idea of what is going on?

Comment: You used static libraries for opencv? and your subprojects?

Comment: I have just updated my error. Previous error was fixed by excluding the library i was talking about from dependencies. Now i get this

Comment: Have you lined against the required library for this symbol?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher, yes the only thing i could find is that it is a struct in opencv. It is contained in camera.hpp header file.

Comment: That's not the missing bit, its CameraParams constructor that is missing.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher  any idea to guide me?

Comment: Nope, I don't have opencv on my box. But you have.